# Problem generify-ing serde_json read into a `Vec<T>` (rust)

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime, serde, serde-json

I have several JSON files that are, at the top level, just arrays with different types of data, so it would be nice to have a function that handles this in a generic way.

This is what I have so far ([rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=87814b5065c0b5221c7b750f30fe9c81)):

```
use std::path::Path;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use serde::Deserialize;

fn get_json<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>>(path: &Path) -> Vec<T> {
    let file = File::open(path).unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    let sentences: Vec<T> = serde_json::from_reader(reader).unwrap();

    sentences
}
```

I don't really understand the error it gives, or how I might convince the borrow-checker that all is good:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: lifetime may not live long enough
    --> src/lib.rs:10:29
     |
6    | fn get_json<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>>(path: &Path) -> Vec<T> {
     |             -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
10   |     let sentences: Vec<T> = serde_json::from_reader(reader).unwrap();
     |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`
     |
note: due to current limitations in the borrow checker, this implies a `'static` lifetime
    --> /playground/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/serde_json-1.0.107/src/de.rs:2591:8
     |
2591 |     T: de::DeserializeOwned,
     |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: implementation of `Deserialize` is not general enough
  --> src/lib.rs:10:29
   |
10 |     let sentences: Vec<T> = serde_json::from_reader(reader).unwrap();
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ implementation of `Deserialize` is not general enough
   |
   = note: `Vec<T>` must implement `Deserialize<'0>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
   = note: ...but it actually implements `Deserialize<'1>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`

error: could not compile `playground` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Just change `Deserialized<'a>` to `DeserializeOwned` (and get rid of the lifetime) and [good things will happen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=10acc7f10acf5028d0fc79d8b0a5c453). The full `Deserialize<'a>` bound supports advanced zero-copy usage that you don't need (and can't use) in your case.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick - thanks!

Comment: I wanted to mark this as duplicate, but somehow I was unable to find a question (and answers) that state this really clearly.

Comment: @user4815162342 Found a good duplicate, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message hints in a very opaque way, you need to change `Deserialized<'a>` to `DeserializeOwned`, and omit the lifetime. That makes your code compile and do what you want:

```
fn get_json<T: DeserializeOwned>(path: &Path) -> Vec<T> {
    let file = File::open(path).unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    serde_json::from_reader(reader).unwrap()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5cbd610bb0f15c4af9bfd7aa54637c51)

The full `Deserialize<'a>` bound is useful when you need zero-copy deserialization, where deserialized data can point the source from which it was deserialized. In your case that is neither possible nor desired, so `DeserializeOwned` is exactly what you want. See [the docs](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html#trait-bounds) for more deails.